# Heroku Build and Deploy Jersey App Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, heroku, jersey, infrastructure

I build a Jersey App using the buildpack provided by heroku and maven project and following this blog : 
https://blog.dejavu.sk/running-jersey-2-applications-on-heroku/?fbclid=IwAR2gc9YoPI8irEa4DVD68PheLCx5pFjdWuc5dKbZmJA5d_D-wjt_-wPTlLo

In my code, I use the type "LocalDate" from the java.time package to work with dates, all was working well in localhost but when I tried to deploy with "git heroku push master" I got into troubles : [image]
Now I had the same with a previous build because I'm using Genson to serialize and deserialize objects and to resolve this I added the dependency via the Maven tool in eclipse and all went well. 
I thought I simply had to do the same for this java.time but I can't find the maven dependency install or even the .jar .
Since it's Java, I assumed it was build-in ... I tried using another library for Time like "Joda-time" but if it's possible to avoid this so I don't have to rewrite every piece of code with LocalDate I'd be interested.

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more details I can just guess:
- Check the import statements in `User` and `UserPersiatance`.
- Check if you configured the right java version (defined in the maven compiler plugin). 
`java.time.LocalDate` only exists since java version **1.8** .

Comment: Thank you, didn't know java.time came with 1.8